# apa6e and biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

Using apa6e with biblatex-apa for the references creates a reference page with the title in bold, and this is not APA. Is there a way to change the format of the title of this section?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\defbibheading` to change the bibliography heading; in the preamble of your document you can say something like

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}{%
  \section*{\normalfont\refname}}
```

or using `\bibname` instead of `\refname`.