# Problem with APA + biber + biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, apa-style

I'm having trouble getting basic APA bibliographies to work. The same thing works with nejm style, but changing the style to apa gives errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mkbibdateapalongextra 
{year}{month}{day}\iffieldundef {endyear}{...

Package biblatex Warning: Macro 'name:apa:last-first' undefined.
(biblatex)                Using \newbibmacro.

Package biblatex Warning: Macro 'name:apa:first-last' undefined.
(biblatex)                Using \newbibmacro.
```

I'm using texlive 2012, as you can see I'm using biber, yes, I reran biber, and also tried delting the .bbl file and rerunning tools. My source markup is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{BibResource.bib}

\begin{document}

test\parencite{ormrod2004human}

\clearpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to declare the language mapping with `babel`.

Comment: See also [problems using apa6e with biblatex-apa](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331/35864).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `\DeclareLanguageMapping` to provide the macros that `biblatex` is expecting.
Note that this requires you to load the `babel` package as well.
See page 231 of the `biblatex` manual for more information.

```
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@Article{rogers:elements,
  author =   {John T. McArthur and A. U. Thor and Steve Rogers},
  title =    {Elements of {A}merica},
  journaltitle = {The Patriot},
  date =     {2013-09-01}}

@Manual{texbook,
  author =  {Donald Ervin Knuth},
  title =   {The \TeX Book},
  address = {Reading},
  year =    {1986}}

@Book{compandtype,
  author =  {Donald Ervin Knuth},
  title =   {Computers \& Typesetting},
  publisher =   {Addison-Wesley},
  address = {Reading},
  year =    {1986},
  descriptor =  {Typesetting},
  annote =  {Computer modern typefaces}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[biblatex,man]{apa6}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\bibliography{refs}

\title{Some Super Psychological Title}
\shorttitle{Psychology Title}
\author{Diligent Student}
\affiliation{\TeX{} StackExchange}

\abstract{This is an abstract!  Woohoo!}
\keywords{example, APA, \LaTeX, education}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Captain America}
A fake citation \parencite{rogers:elements}.
Some filler text. Typography is cool. How cool?
\emph{Very} cool; see \cite{compandtype}.

\section{Another!}
This document was written with \TeX! See also \cite{texbook}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Captain America references courtesy of an [ongoing project](https://github.com/vermiculus/smcm-tex) I'm doing in vain for my school.

Comment: This fixes the "Undefined control sequence" error. The two warnings I mentioned persist, but I can ignore those for now. Thanks!