# How to use biblatex

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am unsuccessfully trying to implement biblatex in my project, so that I can cite other content. I get an error that looks loke this:

```
Undefined control sequence. <argument> \mkbibdateapalongextra 
                                  {year}{month}{day}\iffieldundef {endyear}{... l.15     \printbibliography[heading=bibempty]
                                              The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If
you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget
about whatever was undefined.
```

Can you help me to solve the problem? A minimum code example would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=apa,citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\begin{document}
    My text with a cite\cite{1_nielsen_2011}.

    \printbibliography[heading=bibempty]
\end{document}
```

And the bibliography.bib file has this content:

```
@misc{1_nielsen_2011,
author={Nielsen, Oskar Herrik},
title={Oldmoney.dk | Din genvej til gamle penge},
url={http://www.oldmoney.dk/},
urldate={2015-9-11},
journal={Oldmoney.dk},
year={2011}
}
```

Comment: This is the classic `biblatex-apa` thing, you need `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}` or the appropriate mappping for your language: `\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}` or `\DeclareLanguageMapping{dutch}{dutch-apa}`. Unfortunately, there is no Danish language file as of now.

Comment: See also [Problem with APA + biber + biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136542/35864) as well as [Problem with \mkbibdateapalongextra of biblatex-apa](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133700/35864).

Comment: If you need Danish language support, you could start from one of the Norwegian language files (`nynorsk-apa.lbx`, `norsk-apa.lbx`, `norwegian-apa.lbx`) or just directly from `english-apa.lbx`. If you get a nice `danish-apa.lbx` done I suspect the `biblatex-apa` maintainer would really appreciate your sharing it with him (at [github](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues)).

Comment: @moewe can't I use English even though the document is in danish? I just tried for testing if it worked, so I copied the English language mapping into the line just before `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}`

Comment: If you document is Danish for TeX (i.e. you have `babel` loaded and Danish specified as your document language by `\usepackage[danish]{babel}`) that will not be enough. But if you don't load babel it can work. I would however recommend to load `babel` (or `polyglossia` on XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX).

Comment: In your MWE above, `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}` *will* work. But if you write a document in a language other than American English, you probably want to load `babel` with the appropriate language (`\usepackage[dutch]{babel}`) in which case you will need the appropriate language mapping for your document language (`\DeclareLanguageMapping{dutch}{dutch-apa}`).

Comment: Did you get anywhere?

Comment: @moewe Right now I am wondering if there is another ref. style, that is good for both websites and documents and which support Danish. I am not bound to the apa style and it would remove the problem.

Comment: Standard `authoryear` is also fine. And the standard `biblatex` styles even speak Danish. But if you can invest the time into helping to translate `english-apa.lbx` into Danish, that would help other people with the same problem.

Comment: @moewe that is true

Comment: Anyhow, would you mind if we were to close this question as a duplicate of [Problem with APA + biber + biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136542/35864)?

Comment: @moewe not it is almost the same so you can mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @moewe There is just one thing. When I exhange the apa style with authoryear, it compiles fine. However, it still produces this warning: 

Biber reported the following issues with '1_nielsen_2011': - Datamodel: Entry '1_nielsen_2011' (bibliography.bib): Invalid format '2015-9-11' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring.

Comment: Yup, that is because the date format is invalid, the correct format is `YYYY-MM-DD` so you need `2015-09-11`, leading zeroes are necessary. I had noticed that earlier, but forgot to point it out, sorry.