# APA citing Error

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

Hy everyone!

Im currently using biblatex with style=authoryear. When i quote with \parencite it looks quite similar than apa. But not exactly. There is still a coma between the author and the year i need to get rid of: (Hemingway, 1980, 45) --> (Hemingway 1980, 45). **I tried style=apa but i get Errors.** What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\usepackage{acronym}         

\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}  
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{nameref}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\addbibresource{refrences3.bib}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}   

\begin{document}




Text text text text \parencite[S. 265]{Diepen}

\newpage \defbibheading{bibliography}{% 
\chapter*{Literaturverzeichnis}} 


\printbibliography \setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}

\end{document}
```

Some of the errors i get when i change style=apa:

```
\iffieldundef {endyear}{...
l.745 \setlength
                {\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}
./Introduction.tex:745: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mkbibdateapalongextra 
                                  {year}{month}{day}

Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'retrieved' undefined
(biblatex)                at entry 'Byrum' on input line 744.
```

Comment: You should learn to make better (complete) examples.  The apa-style needs a language mapping: `\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa} `,

Comment: Ok Sorry :)  i still get the errors though

Comment: Your example doesn't use the code I mentioned. It also doesn't use apa style. So how do you know that it still gives the error? And your error mentions line 745, so I doubt very much that you actually compiled the example you show.

Comment: I did. Im gonna edit it the way the errors are showing. The "text" part is just a little longer in my document. line 745 is \printbibliography

Comment: Why did you add the command `\DeclareLanguageMapping` before loading biblatex? Didn't you see that this gives an `! Undefined control sequence.` error straightaway?

Comment: I didnt know that thanks. The errors are now gone but the comma still remains between author and year.

Comment: Well you are explicitly defining this way. What do you think "`\nameyeardelim`" could mean? `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}`.

Comment: The question has evolved quite a bit and is very unclear. The error message is clearly a duplicate of [problems using apa6e with biblatex-apa](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331/35864) and since that is the only thing I can understand about this question and the OP seems to have solved all problems, I'm voting to close as a duplicate of sai question.

Answer (score -1):

Removed `\addcome`

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.