# Only reference key appears when using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style, apa6

I'm trying to include the references directly into the main file. The problem is that citations are undefined and only the reference key will appear.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{gladwell,
    author = {Malcom Gladwell},
    title = {The Tipping Point},
    publisher = {Little, Brown and Company},
    year = {2002}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,man,12pt]{apa6}

\let\Citeauthor\relax

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\let\biblabelsep\relax
\let\bibparsep\relax
\let\bibhang\relax
\let\citename\relax
\let\bibfont\relax
\let\Citeauthor\relax

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}

\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Short}
\author{Some Random Guy}
\affiliation{School}

\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\section{Bla}

\parencite{gladwell}

\subsection{Blubb}

\subsubsection{Lalala}

%\bibliographystyle{apacite}
%\bibliography{jobname}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run `biber` and then recompile at least once more?

Comment: Please check [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751). For `biblatex-apa` you are missing the language mapping `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}` (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331)). The correct call to `\addbibresource` includes the `.bib` file extensions `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}`, this is a problem with some platforms while others are more forgiving. Finally check http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/

Comment: Did the above work for you? If not, what errors/warnings do you get from Biber (`.blg`) and `biblatex` (`.log` file)? What versions are you running?

Comment: @moewe I am new to StackExchange and did not want to spam the comment section (so I only voted up your comment to show that it worked and thank you). `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}` was the missing part in this piece of code. The working code is posted as an answer now in order to help others.

Comment: Ahhh, with up-votes you can never be sure who voted. A short feedback is always appreciated and that would not qualify as spamming the comments. With answers it is a different story, since they can be accepted by the OP. (Still I would say that the approach to comments taken on this site is a very lenient one.) Since you say that it was the language mapping that was missing, I will vote to close your question as a duplicate of the one I linked as reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
```

The command above was the missing piece here (see moewe's comment).

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{gladwell,
    author = {Malcom Gladwell},
    title = {The Tipping Point},
    publisher = {Little, Brown and Company},
    year = {2002}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,man,12pt]{apa6}

\let\Citeauthor\relax

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english} 
\setotherlanguage{russian}

\let\biblabelsep\relax
\let\bibparsep\relax
\let\bibhang\relax
\let\citename\relax
\let\bibfont\relax
\let\Citeauthor\relax

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}

\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Short}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{School
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\section{Recommendations}

\parencite{gladwell}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```