# Problems with "retrieved from" in bibliography produced by BibLaTeX (APA style)

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, apa6

I am using `biblatex` with `apa style`. More or less everything works fine. However, `LaTeX` produces the following warnings

> Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'retrieved' undefined
>   (biblatex)                at entry 'eraut2012' on input line 90.
>
> Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'from' undefined
>   (biblatex)                at entry 'eraut2012' on input line 90.

Moreover, `BibLaTeX` prints the "retrieved from" string in small letters and bold type face:

[image]

**My question therefore is:**

How do I fix this problem? Instead of "**retrieved from**" I need "Retrieved from" to occur in the bibliography.

I already found those discussions: [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36331/problems-using-apa6e-with-biblatex-apa) and [[2]](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2010-08/msg00582.html). However, they did not help.

Ps.: Using `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}` produced the same problem. The `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{...` is necessary because otherwise I do not get a publication year in brackets after the author in the bibliography.

PPs.: I know that this reference would not need a URL in an APA-style bibliography. However, it was the first in my list that had one...

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 

\usepackage[style=apa, sortcites=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{day}%
  \clearfield{month}%
  \clearfield{endday}%
  \clearfield{endmonth}%
}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#1}%
      {}%
      {\thefield{#1}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}%
      {}%
      {\iffieldundef{#1}%
        {}%
        {\addcomma\addspace}%
       \mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}%
      {}%
      {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{#2}\OR\iffieldundef{#1}}%
        {}%
        {\addspace}%
       \stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalongextra#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#1}%
      {}%
      {\thefield{#1}\printfield{extrayear}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}%
      {}%
      {\iffieldundef{#1}%
        {}%
        {\addcomma\addspace}%
       \mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}%
      {}%
      {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{#2}\OR\iffieldundef{#1}}%
        {}%
        {\addspace}%
       \stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalongdmy#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}%
      {}%
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}%
      {}%
      {\iffieldundef{#3}%
        {}%
        {\addspace}%
       \mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}%
      {}%
      {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{#2}\OR\iffieldundef{#3}}%
        {}%
        {\addspace}%
       \thefield{#1}}}}

\begin{filecontents}{apa-test-bib.bib}

@incollection{eraut2012,
    location = {Dordrecht},
    title = {Developing a broader approach to professional learning},
    isbn = {978-94-007-1723-7 978-94-007-1724-4},
    url = {http://www.springerlink.com/index/10.1007/978-94-007-1724-4_2},
    pages = {21--45},
    booktitle = {Learning trajectories, innovation and identity for professional development},
    publisher = {Springer Netherlands},
    author = {Eraut, Michael},
    editor = {Mc Kee, Anne and Eraut, Michael},
    date = {2012},
    langid = {english}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{apa-test-bib.bib}

\begin{document}

This is some text. \cite{eraut2012}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are loading `english` in `babel` you need `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}`; if you want to use `\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}` load `\usepackage[british]{babel}`. The languages have to match exactly. You will find that if you follow either of those suggestions, your `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}` block mentioned in the PS will be superfluous.

Comment: That works perfectly. Would you like to post this as an answer? I am happy to accept it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Update:** With `biblatex-apa` version 7.5 or above and `biblatex` version 3.8 or above (released in November 2017) and explicit `\DeclareLanguageMapping` should not be needed for `biblatex-apa` any more. The mapping will be automatically executed for all supported languages. This means that this answer has essentially become obsolete. Update your TeX system if possible.
>
> Note that at the time of writing this note (July 2019) Overleaf is still running an outdated system, where `\DeclareLanguageMapping` is still needed for `biblatex-apa`.
>
> The rest of the answer is kept below for historical interest and people stuck with older systems.

The languages you request for `babel` and the language mappings need to match.

Either use

```
\usepackage[british]{babel} 
...
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
```

for British English, or use

```
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
...
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
```

for American English (without US punctuation).

In your MWE your document is in `english`, and you told `biblatex` to request `british-apa` instead of `british`, effectively changing nothing for you since you didn't request `british` in the first place.

Another symptom of this was that you needed the `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}` block for the dates. With matching languages that is no longer necessary.

Comment: This also fixed `! Undefined control sequence. \blx@unitpunct ->\urldatecomma` for me, caused by `american-apa`.

Comment: @phg With recent versions of `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` the `\DeclareLanguageMapping` should not be needed any more.

Comment: Good to know. `biblatex` 3.6 and `biblatex-apa` 7.2 seem not to be recent enough, though. I should upgrade from TeXLive 2016 some time...

Comment: @phg You'll need at least `biblatex` 3.8 and `biblatex-apa` 7.5 from November 2017. The current versions are 3.11 and 7.7