# printbibliography in LaTeX beamer causes errors and warnings (string retrieved undefined)

Tags: beamer, biblatex, apa-style

As long as I don't use `\printbibliography` command, my document compiles without errors and warnings.

Once I try to print bibliography, I get following messages:

```
Undefined control sequence.<argument> \datecircaprint \mkbibdateapalongextra {labelyear}{labelmonth}{la... l.78 \end{frame}
Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'retrieved' undefined at entry 'some-3' on input line 78.
Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'from' undefined at entry 'some-3' on input line 78.
```

and strange strings in bibliography such as `labelyearlabelmonthlabelday).`:

[image: strange characters in bibliography]

According to: [Problems with "retrieved from" in bibliography produced by BibLaTeX (APA style)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319551/problems-with-retrieved-from-in-bibliography-produced-by-biblatex-apa-style),
I've tried to resolve it by adding:

```
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{polish}{polish-apa}
```

but it doesn't help.

---

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress, xcolor={usenames, dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=authoryear, natbib=true]{biblatex}
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers={i inni},and={i}} %% Mentioned strings are in polish, not english.

    % According to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202988/beamer-patching-footnotes-warning-patching-footnotes-failed-footnote-detectio
    % Filter warnings issued by package biblatex starting with "Patching footnotes failed"
    \usepackage{silence,lmodern}
    \WarningFilter{biblatex}{Patching footnotes failed}
    \addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{polski}
    \uselanguage{polish}
    \languagepath{polish}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{multirow}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   TITLE PAGE definition
\logo{%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{smiley.pdf}~%
}

\title[Short title]{This is a long title displayed only on the title page}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author[short author]{Autor: I am an author\break{\small co-author: this is coauthor}}

\institute[some]
{
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0.7pt} % default value: 6pt
    \begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \label{tab:Tabelka}
    \begin{tabular}{cl}
    \includegraphics[width=0.08\linewidth, valign=c]{smiley-orange.pdf} & My University \\[.2cm] %scale=0.05,
    \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.05\linewidth, valign=c]{smiley-green.pdf}} & My Faculty,               \\
                          & in two lines                                                    \\[.2cm]
    \includegraphics[width=0.04\linewidth, valign=c]{smiley.pdf}                  & My department %scale=0.1
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{6pt} % default value: 6pt
}

\date{15.11.2017}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage 
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}

%------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some information}

Thus I will cite: \citep{some-1, some-2}.

I would like to cite \citep{some-3} as well.
\end{frame}

\section*{}
\appendix

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{References}
  {\footnotesize \printbibliography}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and `bibliografia.bib` file:

```
@article{some-3,
    author = "XYW, Cl{\'e}ment and T{\"u}ger, Andrew",
    hal_id = "hydro-004455129",
    hal_version = "v1",
    journal = "{some Journal}",
    month = dec,
    pages = "1323--1337",
    pdf = "https://no-such-page/test.pdf",
    publisher = "{LaTeX Publications}",
    title = "{From LaTeX to PDF}",
    url = "https://no-such-page/2wtr-003e4329",
    volume = "2",
    year = "2009"
}

@article{some-1,
  title   = "LaTeX in space",
  journal = "TeX Journal ",
  volume  = "17(1)",
  pages   = "113--122",
  year    = "2015",
  doi     = "",
  author  = "Thomas Key"
}

@ARTICLE{some-2, 
    author={RtV, Y. and ODW, P. and Tom, J.-P.}, 
    journal={Proceedings of the TeX}, 
    title={{The} {LaTeX} {Mission}}, 
    year={2014}, 
    volume={980}, 
    number={5}, 
    pages={66-67}, 
    abstract={Long text here}, 
    keywords={keyword 1; keyword 2; keyword 3}, 
    doi={10.999999/e434EXW}, 
    ISSN={0112-5319}, 
    month={05},
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
```

Works when I run your example, i.e.,

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress, xcolor={usenames, dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polski}
\uselanguage{polish}
\languagepath{polish}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=authoryear, natbib=true]{biblatex}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{polish}{andothers={i inni},and={i}} %% Mentioned strings are in polish, not english.

    % According to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202988/beamer-patching-footnotes-warning-patching-footnotes-failed-footnote-detectio
    % Filter warnings issued by package biblatex starting with "Patching footnotes failed"
    \usepackage{silence,lmodern}
    \WarningFilter{biblatex}{Patching footnotes failed}
    \addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   TITLE PAGE definition
\logo{%
}

\title[Short title]{This is a long title displayed only on the title page}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author[short author]{Autor: I am an author\break{\small co-author: this is coauthor}}

\institute[some]
{
}

\date{15.11.2017}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage 
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}

%------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some information}

Thus I will cite: \citep{some-1, some-2}.

I would like to cite \citep{some-3} as well.
\end{frame}

\section*{}
\appendix

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{References}

  {\footnotesize \printbibliography}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is because `biblatex-apa` has no `polish-apa.lbx`, so falls back to English, where we still need `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}`. With `biblatex` 3.8/`biblatex-apa` 7.5 `\DeclareLanguageMapping` is not needed for `biblatex-apa` any more.