# style=apa causes bibliography to fail

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style, apa6

I need to write an article with APA citations. I have sample code that works fine with `style=authoryear`, but if I switch to `style=apa` I get the following error message:

```
Error Line 21 ! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \printdateextralabel
```

I'm using TexMaker with `biber`. I've gone through example after example and I can't figure out what's wrong. I suspected it was with TexMaker or MiKTeX, but I just uninstalled and reinstalled both programs and I'm having the same issue. The same error message always pops up with the line number after `\printbibliography`. I tried copying corrected MWE's from other questions (such as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36331/problems-using-apa6e-with-biblatex-apa) answered by Alan Munn) and I get the same error.  I included a MWE and my `.bib` file (borrowed from another thread) below.

File MWE:

```
\documentclass[article,12pt,letterpaper]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}


\title{Annotated Bibliography 1}
\author{Joe Smith}
\affiliation{Spectacular University}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\abstract{abstract goes here}
\maketitle
this is a test
\cite{Kim1999188}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

bib:

```
@article{Kim1999188,
title = "Absorption of water vapour into lithium bromide-based solutions with additives using a simple stagnant pool absorber ",
journal = "International Journal of Refrigeration ",
volume = "22",
number = "3",
pages = "188 - 193",
year = "1999",
note = "",
issn = "0140-7007",
doi = "10.1016/S0140-7007(98)00061-9",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0140700798000619",
author = "Jin-Soo Kim and Huen Lee and Sun Il Yu",
keywords = "Absorption",
keywords = "Water",
keywords = "Lithium bromide",
keywords = "Absorption",
keywords = "Eau",
keywords = "Bromure de lithium "
}
```

[image: Commands Tab]
[image: Quick Build]

Here is a link to my [Log File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B79Q6nTY2RIgNl9GRWowcVhLWVE/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*`biblatex-apa` has been updated to use the new commands introduced in `biblatex` 3.5, if you still have this problem, make sure to update your `biblatex` styles. The modifications described in the answer below should not be necessary any more. If you have a similar problem with another style, update the style and contact the maintainer if the problem persists.*

The date format handling has been drastically changed in `biblatex` 3.5, some of these changes are not backwards compatible. [See the release notes](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/CHANGES.org).

One of the changes is that `\printdateextralabel` has been renamed. With

```
\def\printdateextralabel{\printlabeldateextra}
```

you can get back the old name, so `biblatex-apa` does not throw errors any more.

The [github version of `biblatex-apa`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa) is already updated to work properly with `biblatex` 3.5 and use the new features, but on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa) we still only have version 6.9.
PLK has just submitted version 7.0 to CTAN (see [this github ticket](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/26)) so it should be available in MikTeX and TeX live in a few days.

The MWE

```
\documentclass[article,12pt,letterpaper]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\def\printdateextralabel{\printlabeldateextra}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

works just fine, but issues some warning messages about deprecated commands and options.

Comment: thanks for the answer and pointing to the CHANGELOG of biblatex; it greatly helped me debugging/understanding a similar problem and saved my day.