# Getting "Undefined control sequence" error

Tags: biblatex

When I'm trying to compile a bibliography, I keep getting the "undefined control sequence" error. I'm guessing this is due to some problem in the bib file, but I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Tex code:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{ref2.bib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\title{ORT}
\shorttitle{Ortho}
\author{name}
\affiliation{univ name}
\leftheader{surname}
\authornote{None}
\abstract{None}
\listfiles

\begin{document}
Blah blah blah \parencite{Smith1999}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bib entry:

```
@article{Smith1999,
author = {Smith, Bob},
journal = {Journal},
number = {1},
pages = {47--84},
title = {{Article Name}},
volume = {14},
year = {1999}
}
```

I keep getting the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \printdateextralabel 

l.20 \end
         {document}
?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see this with a TeX Live system updated this morning

Comment: I'm using TeXWorks, and I've updated all the packages. the `\printbibliography` line doesn't work, period. This is really frustrating...

Comment: Your example works on my system. Make sure you actually run biber

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt Biber is running, since if I remove the `\printbibliography` line, the inline citation works and the file compiles successfully to pdf.

Comment: Try to remove all temporary file which had been created by latex or biber and keep only your files. There may be a problem with some old temp files.

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt Still getting the error. :(

Comment: Try to identify which package causes the error i.e. use
`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref2.bib}
\begin{document}
\parencite{Smith1999}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
` and not more. Clean temp files and re-run biber as you will get an error the first time compiling this without the apa style.

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt It appears to be the apa6 package. It's a bit puzzling, since when I downloaded biber from the original source and replaced it, it ran properly... and then upon the second run of biber, the process crashed.

Comment: Most latex/biber programs need multiple runs. Check for updates of the apa6 package and eventually provide bug-report for the package maintainer https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apa6?lang=en

Comment: Reported them as bugs.

Comment: I get the error with the article.cls (and the biblatex-apa style) too. Imho it is a biblatex-apa problem and will be corrected in short time. Add `\newcommand\printdateextralabel{XXXX}` to your document and wait until the new release is there.

Comment: Should be a duplicate of [style=apa causes bibliography to fail](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329411/35864), the problem is resolved in `biblatex-apa` 7.0 which should be available soon.