# Biber - "cite" macro fails at second compilation, while entry is found in the bibliography

Tags: pdftex, biber

I am trying to set up a bibliography with BibLatex. Even a single `\cite{}` statement causes an error upon second compilation with `pdflatex` after running `biber`.

The sequence of running the commands is as follows:

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
biber mwe (optionally multiply by 2 and/or add a bcf extension)
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

After running biber and trying to run pdflatex for the second time the engine errors at `\cite{aa}` and no bibliography gets printed.

Here is the minimal (not yet) working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, date=short, style=apa]{biblatex}
\title{some title}
\author{Authorov A. A.}
\date{\today}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@misc{aa,
  author = {Some Author A.},
  title = {Some title},
  year = {2016}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Some sentence\cite{aa}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Blg file output:

```
[0] Config.pm:354> INFO - This is Biber 2.7
[1] Config.pm:357> INFO - Logfile is 'mwe.blg'
[28] biber-MSWIN64:303> INFO - === 
[51] Biber.pm:359> INFO - Reading 'mwe.bcf'
[136] Biber.pm:835> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[149] Biber.pm:3670> INFO - Processing section 0
[168] Biber.pm:3840> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'references.bib' for section 0
[171] bibtex.pm:1435> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[176] bibtex.pm:1292> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'references.bib'
[187] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[187] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[188] Biber.pm:3499> INFO - Sorting list 'apa/global/' of type 'entry' with scheme 'apa' and locale 'en-US'
[189] Biber.pm:3505> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
[191] bbl.pm:608> INFO - Writing 'mwe.bbl' with encoding 'ascii'
[192] bbl.pm:712> INFO - Output to mwe.bbl
```

I am running MikTex 2.9 (64-bit), Biber 2.7 and Windows 10.

Having had a look through similar questions, they either do not use Biber or the problem seems to have a different root. Would appreciate any hints and tips. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What _exactly_ is the error?

Comment: Upon running Biber the error is "Warn: I didn't find a database entry for 'aa'", when running pdflatex for the second time I get: "l.16 Some sentence\cite{aa}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!". Judging by Biber output, it does find the bib file though: "Found BibTeX data source 'references.bib'"

Comment: The edit doesn't show the issue you describe: the entry is found!

Comment: Sorry about this. Probably due to minimizing this example this error has somehow dissapeared. I will edit the title accordingly for bibliography not being printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, date=short, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{aa,
  author = {Some Author A.},
  title = {Some title},
  year = {2016}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\def\printdateextralabel{\printlabeldateextra}

\title{some title}
\author{Authorov A. A.}
\date{\today}



\begin{document}
\maketitle
Some sentence\cite{aa}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I coopied code from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329497/120578

Posible duplicate with the above.

Comment: Well, this worked with american-apa! I can also confirm that this worked with using British babel and british-apa too. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: welcome. Glad that this fixed your issue.