# APA Style Document Won't Compile

Tags: bibliographies, errors, citing, apa-style

By any chance would someone help me use the APA style? I cannot not get it to work for the life of me. I've googled all around, but there seems to be a million APA packages out there. I just want a simple APA format where the intext citation would be: (Author, 2007), and the bibliography ordered alphabetically.

[By the way, I'm new to LaTeX, so sorry if I am difficult or lacking in knowledge.]

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apa6}
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    style=apalike,
    sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{wage.bib}
\title{Title}
\author{name}
\date{14 November 2016}



\begin{document}


\nocite{*}

 Hello,  testing testing\footcite{ninefity}. Let's do another     citation.\footcite{realwage}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Using the same wage.bib file:

```
\begin{filecontents}{wage.bib}


@article{realwage,
author =       "Orley Ashenfelter",
title =        "Comparing Real Wage Rates",
journal =      "American Economic Association",
volume =       "102",
number =       "2",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "2012",
}



@article{ninefity,
author =       "Joseph Sabia and RIchard Burkenhauser",
title =        "Minimum Wages and Poverty: Will a 9.50 Federal     Minimum IWage Really Help the Working Poor?",
journal =      "Southern Economic Journal",
volume =       "76",
number =       "3",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "2010",
}

@article{politics,
author =       "Russell Sobel",
title =        "Theory and Evidence on the Political Economy of the Minimum Wage",
journal =      "Journal of Political Economy",
volume =       "107",
number =       "4",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "1999",
}
```

What seems to be the trouble is the \bibliographystyle{apalike} command. It refuses to read it no matter what I do. Is the APA package incompatible with the biblatex backend? Do I need to download a specific package?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`apa6` is a class, not a package. It should be `\documentclass{apa6}`.
You should either use `\bibliography{wage}` or  `\addbibresource{wage.bib}`.
The syle `apalike` does not go well with biblatex, I'd recommend using the real thing, apa style with biber. APA 6 does not allow `\footcite` for one column documents use `\documentclass[twocolum]{apa6}` if you want it to be a two columns document.

Here's my working fix

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa,
sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{wage}
\title{Title}
\author{name}
\date{14 November 2016}



\begin{document}


    \nocite{*}

    Hello,  testing testing \cite{ninefity}. Let's do another  citation. \cite{realwage}.

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I still get an error. This is what the error says:

     Undefined control sequence.
     <argument> \mkbibdateapalongextra 
                                       {year}{month}{day}\iffieldundef {endyear}{...

Is it perhaps the case that I formatted the bib file incorrectly? It appears to take issue with the date of the citation. Yesterday, I somehow managed to compile it (with the error still present), and while the intext citation came out perfectly, the bibliography citations showed weird formatting. For instance, this is a rough example (recalling from memory): Sobel (authoryear)

Comment: The parentheses in the bib file might be causing problems as well, try replacing them with `{` `}`. i.e. `author = {Some Author}`.

Comment: You'll need `\DeclareLanguageMapping` and should load `babel` even if the document is in American English, see [problems using apa6e with biblatex-apa](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331/35864)

Answer (score 1):

In case you continue to experience difficulties with biblatex's implementation of the APA bibliography formatting requirements, I suggest you switch to loading the `apacite` package, using the `apacite` bibliography style, and employing BibTeX.

You really, really also ought to make a serious effort to get the *contents* of all bibliographic entries correct. For example, the name of one of the journals is *not* "American Economic Association"; it's "American Economic Review". The surname of one of the authors is *not* "Burkenhauser"; it's "Burkhauser". That entry's `title` field currently contains two [2!] additional errors: a missing `$` symbol, and "iwage" instead of just "wage". And, why do you omit all authors' middle initials? Nothing good can come from such sloppiness.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{wage.bib}
@article{realwage,
author =       "Orley C. Ashenfelter",
title =        "Comparing Real Wage Rates",
journal =      "American Economic Review",
volume =       "102",
number =       "2",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "2012",
}
@article{ninefity,
author =       "Joseph J. Sabia and Richard V. Burkhauser",
title =        "Minimum Wages and Poverty: Will a \$9.50 Federal Minimum Wage Really Help the Working Poor?",
journal =      "Southern Economic Journal",
volume =       "76",
number =       "3",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "2010",
}
@article{politics,
author =       "Russell S. Sobel",
title =        "Theory and Evidence on the Political Economy of the Minimum Wage",
journal =      "Journal of Political Economy",
volume =       "107",
number =       "4",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "1999",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\frenchspacing

\begin{document}
\citep{ninefity}, \citep{realwage}, \citep{politics}
\bibliography{wage}
\end{document}
```