# Problems with \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am writing my thesis and need to do this with apa citation style.

I used the following code in my main document:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sorting=none,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib} 
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
```

and in the end of my main document..

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,[title={References}]
```

However I always get this error:

> "Undefined control sequence.
>   \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,[title={References}]"

Furthermore in my references table, I get (yearmonthday) instead of (2015)e.g. and the references are not alphabetically sorted.

Comment: You need a `\DeclareLanguageMapping` for your language (i.e. the language set as main language in `babel`: `\DeclareLangugaMapping{american}{american-apa}`), see [problems using apa6e with biblatex-apa](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331/35864).

Comment: Also, you have an additional opening square bracket in the argument of `\printbibliography`. Presumably, you want `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=References]` The curly brackets around `References` are fine, but the opening square bracket before `title` is not. @moewe Should `csquotes` be loaded before `biblatex`? I always load it first, but I don't know if that's required.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, both explanations are not the reason :(

Comment: While I use \printbibliography without an option, your heading seems to be not support. Biblatex supports Bibliopgraphy and shorthands See sec 3.7.2 in the biblatex manual (on ctan)
@cfr I load csquotes after biblatex, but supply the babel package as input

Comment: @ChristophS It is defined. Those are just the defaults if you don't specify one. See sec 3.7.7 for the list of predefined options.

Comment: @cfr Just noticed that. I am just providing a functioning example in an answer

Comment: Loading order doesn't matter, I see.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? If not, please provide an [MWEB](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that also addresses the comments you have already gotten (`\DeclareLanguageMapping` etc.). Please show us the error/waning messages you receive, the `.blg` file and describe what is wrong with the output.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you have to check for when using biblatex. Some of them were already outlined in the comments.
The `\printbibliography` should look like `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=References]`
To start, here Is a functioning example from my template I use:

```
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa} %Literaturverzeichnis american-apa style
\addbibresource{library.bib} 
\usepackage[babel,threshold=2]{csquotes}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you have a bracket closed too much.

Try using this instead:

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
```

Comment: Note that Christoph S mentions the same thing in his answer - though not as explicit. Plus when the problematic bracing was mentioned in the comments the OP responded that that was not the only error.