# apa style in my thesis

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, apa6, back-referencing

could somebody help me with my APA references for my thesis?
This is my code and all the packages that I include.

```
\documentclass[
11pt, 
english, 
onehalfspacing 
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{palatino} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sorting=none,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib} 
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{pfnote}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=rm}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin=0pt, parskip=0pt, hangindent=0pt, indention=0pt, labelformat=parens, labelfont=rm}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]   <<-- here I always get the error: Undefined control sequence
```

I get a table with references, almost in the right way but unfortunately not alphabetically sorted and with "yearmonthday" in brackets instead of the year of publication.

Does somebody know my mistake? Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a double post. I just provided you a working example in your other thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351079/problems-with-printbibliography

Comment: Hi welcome, the formatting is a bit messed up. Can youn provide a minimal working example? I am almost sure, that the given class has nothing to do with it. Maybe make it independent by stating [that it relies on standard boo](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual).

Comment: If you want to write a scientific report, maybe have a look at [scientific report](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports)

Comment: @ChristophS : Your example does not work for my code, I do not know why ( I changed the bib. document source ;) )

Comment: @Johannes_B : Yes, I use this template already but this is not APA style. With numbers it worked perfect.

Comment: @Bernard : Thanks for making my code readable :)

Comment: You're welcome. Yet, it is not compilable. Note that, to make a code readable, the simplest is to select it and click on the braces icon in the toolbar.

Comment: Any reason for loading the `biblatex` package twice?

Comment: no, without this line "\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}" I get the same result

Comment: Your argument natbib which you specify for biblatex is incomptaible, see section 1.5.4 of the biblatex manual.

Comment: True, I can also remove that. However I can still not solve my problem -.-

Comment: @Johanna I tried a bit around an fixed it: http://pastebin.com/4VbeQvA8

Comment: Thank you a lot! This is brilliant :) Do you possibly also know how to print only the references in the bibliography that I used in the document?

Comment: figured it out- I used Biber instead of bibtex to run it :P