# With Apa6 Class and Biblatex: Undefined Control Sequence \end

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa6

I've been attempting to get BiblaTeX to work with the Apa6 Document class. However, when I run `pdflatex`, `biber`, and `pdflatex` again, I get two errors:

- Undefined Control Sequence. `testtesttest \cite{Example01}`
- Undefined Control Sequence. `\end`

Here is my tex file:

```
\documentclass[doc,12pt,biblatex]{apa6}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\shorttitle{Short APA title}

\begin{document}

 testtesttest \cite{Example01}

 \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is my bibliography file:

```
@misc { Example01,
  author = "Bob Smith",
  title = "A Million Random Stories with 100,000 Normal Characters",
  publisher = "Bob's Publishing",
  year = "2017"
}
@book { Example02,
  author = "John Doe",
  title = "Lorem Ipsum 2: The Lipsuming",
  publisher = "Doe Books",
  year = "2016"
}
```

**Notes**

- I'm using pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
- I'm using biber 2.7 (beta)
- I only need to remove the `\cite{Example01}` phrase, and it compiles completely
- The pdflatex appears to compile an incomplete version of the citations, eg. the citation looks like "Smith, labelyearlabelmonthlabelday" and the bibliography is similar.
- I'm using the `texlive-full` and `texlive-publishers` packages on Ubuntu  17.10.

Comment: Add `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}` to your preamble.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: See also [problems using apa6e with biblatex-apa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331/35864)

Answer (score 0):

According to @mowewe, I needed to add `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}` to my preamble.

The latex file compiled without error.