# APA in text citations not working

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I'm struggling using the APA citation style, and would like to see in text citations in the form (Author, Date) in the text, but I either get an error compiling or `{labelyear}{labelmonth}` after every citation in my console.

Here is the top matter in my latex document... am I missing something/using contradicting packages?

Here is the code snippet.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report} % Use the report document class if you're looking to include chapters, otherwise article is fine
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%packages allowing for images to be inserted 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\graphicspath{ {thesisimages/} }
%packages for formatting Figures 
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}
%packages pertaining to the bibliography

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{thesisbib.bib}

%packages pertaining to formatting
\linespread{1.6}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in,9in}]{geometry}
%package for the degree symbol
\usepackage{gensymb}
%package for making subFigures(below)
\usepackage{subfig}
%package for including quotes (below)
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
%package for changing the line spacing in bibliography
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
%package for including pdf packages
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%package for appendices?
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

These people said explained some things \cite{Haralick1979} \cite{Hodges2003}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If I comment out `dirtytalk` which for some reason is not available on my MikTeX system everything compiles smoothly. Please try to break down the example even further. Does the problem still persists with the code at https://gist.github.com/moewew/685539e2b17c0c1880cefbb28582d495? If so, please show us the `.log` and `.blg` file after the LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX build cycle. If something goes wrong you should be getting error messages, what do they say?

Comment: Any news here? As mentioned above your code works for me on an up-to-date system. If you are running an older system it could be that you need a `\DeclareLanguageMapping` line, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331/35864. But without the specific error message and more detailed information that is just guessing. Please update your question with the information requested in my last comment.

Comment: Hi Moewe, thanks for you response! The problem still persists when I use the code that you posted (gist.github.com/moewew/685539e2b17c0c1880cefbb28582d495), and I get the following error: 

<argument> \datacircaprint \mkbibdateapalongextra {labelyear}{labelmonth}{la...
l.14. \end
{document}
?

When I commented dirtytalk, I get an error for each citation when I compile the document.

Comment: Here is the entry for Haralick1979:
@article{Haralick1973,
 author = {Haralick, R.M. and Shanmugam, K. and Dinstein, I.},
 journal = {IEEE Transactions on Systems, Man, and cybernetics},
 pages = {610--621},
 title = {{Textural Features for Image Classification}},
 volume = {3},
 year = {1973}
}

Comment: Your version of `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` are outdated and possibly incompatible (not too sure). Can you make an update? In old versions of `biblatex` you need `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331/35864.

Comment: I think I figured it out using the snippet of code that you posted earlier. Thank you for your help!

Comment: So how did you solve this? What was the problem?

Comment: Any news here? Currently I am assuming that https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331/35864 solved your problem, can you confirm that?